# How to keep current URL updated in QWebKit browser

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebkit, qurl

I am making a very simple browser with a search box using PyQt5 WebKit. This is the code I'm using:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QAction, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QMainWindow, QGridLayout)
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        centralWidget   = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.searchbox = QLineEdit("", self)
        self.go = QPushButton('Go', self)
        self.go.clicked.connect(self.gourl)  
        self.webview = Browser()        

        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.webview, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.searchbox, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.go, 1, 1)

    def gourl(self):
        url = self.searchbox.text()
        self.webview.load(QUrl(url))


class Browser(QWebView):   #(QWebView):
    windowList = []
    def createWindow(self, QWebEnginePage_WebWindowType):
        App.setCentralWidget(Browser())
        #new_window.show()
        self.windowList.append(App())  
        return Browser()

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    box = App()
    box.setWindowTitle('Browser')
    box.resize(600, 500)
    box.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to keep the URL in the box updated with whatever current URL the user is on. I have no idea how to go about this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a re-write of your example which should do what you want.

The `Browser` class has been fixed so that it creates a new instance of `App` when a new window is requested. You can test this by right-clicking on a link and selecting *Open in New Window*. The search box will automatically update with the new url whenever it changes.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QAction, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QMainWindow, QGridLayout)
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        centralWidget   = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.searchbox = QLineEdit("", self)
        self.go = QPushButton('Go', self)
        self.go.clicked.connect(self.gourl)
        self.webview = Browser()
        self.webview.urlChanged.connect(self.handleUrlChanged)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.webview, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.searchbox, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.go, 1, 1)

    def gourl(self):
        url = self.searchbox.text()
        self.webview.load(QUrl(url))

    def handleUrlChanged(self, url):
        self.searchbox.setText(url.toString())


class Browser(QWebView):
    windowList = []

    def createWindow(self, wintype):
        window = App()
        self.windowList.append(window)
        window.show()
        return window.webview

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.windowList.remove(self)
        super().closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    box = App()
    box.setWindowTitle('Browser')
    box.resize(600, 500)
    box.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: you must to check if QLineEdit text is a valid Url or will crash right?

Comment: @Linux No, it won't crash. It just won't load the url - and then either show an error page, or *about:blank*. But what exactly do you mean by "valid"? If you mean *syntactically valid*, then I suppose you could use `url = QUrl.fromUserInput(text)` and check `url.isValid()`. However, if you mean *semantically valid*, then it's impossible to know - a http request could return a 404 or 503 (or whatever) at any time. It's really a waste of time trying to work out in advance what *might happen* - just let the browser deal with it